# 'ModuleNotFoundError' in VS Code with Anaconda Environment, despite the module having been installed

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, version, modulenotfounderror

I am using VS Code and am trying to import different modules (e.g. `os`). I am in an Anaconda Environment using `Python 3.10.13`, where I have installed all the modules (via `conda install`) I want to import into my file. When I use VS Code for other projects (in other directories) it works just fine. For some reason though, I always get the `'ModuleNotFoundError'` when trying it on all files in the current folder.

When I run a cell (in a .py file) it starts up the kernel of the selected environment and it prints on the Interactive panel the following text:

```
Connected to Python 3.12.0
```

and this although I have installed `Python 3.10.13` in my Environment and not `Python 3.12.0`.

This might be the source of the error, however I do not know how I would change that. This is what the error message looks like. On the bottom right you can see that I am in fact connected to my environment, where i installed Python 3.10.13:

[image: My Error]

I tried reinstalling the modules via `conda install`, I tried setting up a new environment, I tried different Python versions (can't upgrade to 3.12.0 since tensorflow won't work). The only thing that works is using a .ipynb file in the same environment, but since I am working with .py files, this won't do for me.

Comment: Please post the error as text, not a screenshot.

Comment: What if you opened a terminal and run `python --version`. This should give you `3.10.13`. If everything goes well I would perhaps even use the terminal then, to run with a brute force `python my_script.py`.

Comment: @toyotaSupra: it actually is `ModuleNotFoundError`, which is included in the corrected post

Comment: maybe you have to change configuration in `VSCode` to run it with expected version `3.10`. Or you have to use `python3.12 -m pip install ...` to install all needed modules.

Answer (score 0):

You can use shortcuts "Ctrl+Shift+P" and type "Python: Select Interpreter" to change your python interpreter.

Then clicking the button on the top-right to choose your jupyter kernel which you installed the python package `torch`.

[image]

Another way to solve it is to install torch package in the current python interpreter in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the same problem (wrong Python version and no module found error) by setting the Python Conda path in VS Code.

I first checked that VS Code was using the right Conda environment (Ctrl+Shift+P 'Python: Select Interpreter), but it made no difference and kept returning 'No module named...' errors.

To fix it, try opening the settings in VS Code (Ctrl+) and typing in 'conda' in the search box at the top of the page.
[Settings in VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdPya.png)

Then set the Python Conda path to your base Conda Python executable (in my case on Windows, it was: C:\Users\[username]\anaconda3\python.exe) and restart VS Code (with double back-slash for Windows).

If that doesn't work, try setting the specific Conda environment path (ie. C:\Users\[username]\anaconda3\envs\[environment_name]\python.exe on Windows), but that's not an ideal fix as it will always reference that Conda environment.

See the instructions: https://docs.anaconda.com/free/anaconda/configurations/python-path/ to get the path for your OS and setup.

BTW - before making that fix, I found that 'Run Code' in VS Code would fail ('no module named...'), but running from the Terminal worked (i.e. either typing 'python filename.py' in the Terminal or by selecting 'Run Python File' from the dropdown).

[VS Code Run Code and Run Python File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMc68.png)